# Gparted showing up as whole disk unallocated (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, gparted, fdisk

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on a desktop and when opening gparted I got the error

"The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used."

Here is what my gparted shows [image: currentgparted]

Previously it looked like [image: oldgparted]

The (edited to remove inapplicable data) output of
    sudo fdisk -l; mount 
is

```
Snip


The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2FDEB336-49AA-4624-9958-4A2D2AF7B388

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Snip

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Snip nothing from /dev/sda mounted.
```

I am too scared to reboot my system. Is this a huge issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately u have deleted all partitions so they seem to be unallocated..Just like rebuilding mbr table..in ur case u have to repair GPT disk...i recommend using minitool partition wizard or ease us partition master for that (in bootable format)

Comment: How could I have done that without going near my partitions?

Comment: Is ur system still booting:/ ?

Comment: I mean I've had no issues, it's booting and everything seems to be running, I haven't even been messing about with partitions, I just checked gparted because my computer seemed a little sluggish and now I am scared to reboot

Comment: Oh ohk...then this is error because of incorrect GPT table for ur gpt disk..i don't know if their is option like rebuild GPT...just like MBR :/.. one way i know to recreate proper gpt is wiping out all disks and create new gpt disk...wait for other solutions

Comment: CHeck [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) how to install `testdisk` and check
[here](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/t/testdisk/install/index.html) for instructions
how to use it. You can install in live-session booted from Installer (Try Ubuntu without installing)...

Comment: You might just reboot and see what happens, 'cause there's nothing that you're gonna be able to do from here. You'll need to boot to external CD/DVD's to fix the problem. It just looks too wierd. Now it shows a 4TB disk. You showed a 2TB disk. Partitions are not aligned. 360GB unallocated. Somebody has been 'messing with partitions. Cheers, Al

Comment: You show an extended partition which is only in MBR(msdos) partitioning in your old image. So issues with gpt are not related to your normally partitioning. You normally do not have both MBR & gpt. Some old Mac computers needed a hybrid to boot Windows in BIOS/MBR mode. Since you have Windows and it only boots in BIOS mode with MBR,  you cannot convert to gpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous image of your drive shows an extended partition containing logical partitions.  This configuration is not possible with GPT which means that your previous partition was likely MSDOS (aka MBR).

At some point in time, GPT signatures must have been written to the drive.  Since you mention that your computer still boots and functions then that implies that the old MSDOS partition table is still intact.  This is good news.

Before attempting to correct this situation I highly recommend making a backup of all your data.  That way you won't lose your data if anything goes wrong such as a hardware failure, power outage, or software bug while you attempt a fix.

To keep the old MSDOS partition table and only remove the GPT signatures.  See the following tutorial on [Wiping Out Old GPT Data](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/wipegpt.html).  The tutorial recommends using **fixparts** as the safest way to keep the MSDOS (aka MBR) partition table while wiping out the GPT signatures.